# failed to unregister w3wp when running codecoverage tool from Visual Studio 2012 on release bits

Tags: .net, iis, visual-studio-2012, code-coverage

I am getting the following warning logged in the event viewer when I run code coverage tool that comes with Visual Studio 2012 SP1 (`<VS folder>\Team Tools\Dynamic Code Coverage`) and as a result the output .coverage file does not contain any coverage data:

> Failed to unregister 'w3wp.exe', this process will be launched using
>   DEBUG_PROCESS flag. The behavior of application might be different.

The command I run from cmd line (with Administrator rights) is:
codecoverage collect /IIS /session:test /output:myfile.coverage

I would also like to point out that I do have the .pdb files in the same folder as all the bianries (I know .pdb files are needed for dlls instrumentation step)

I reproed this on both Widows Server  2008 R2 with IIS 7 and Windows Server 2012 with IIS 8, so I don't since it's smth config/environment specific, but I might be wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: I also get the same warning on Windows 7, but after I run _codecoverage shutdown/:session:test_, the output gets streamed to the file.

Comment: Do you also gat any other subsequent warnings / errors?

Comment: I also run shutdown /session:test and the generated .coverage file has ony ~ 50 kb and contains the following error:   Empty results generated: No binaries were instrumented. Make sure the tests ran, required binaries were loaded, had matching symbol files, and were not excluded through custom settings. For more information see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=253731

Comment: ...and I do not get any other subsequent warnings/errors

Comment: Actually I realized that I also get this error when the .coverage file gets correctly created...so the issue is with the release bits (with debug bits works just fine). Did anyone encounter this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to get to the bottom of this. For the release build, there were 2 things I needed to change in the .config file

- specify the path to the Symbols (apparently this is needed even if the .pdf files are in the same location as the dlls)
- I had to remove the default  exclusion list since these included Microsoft public key tokens and our product is a Microsoft product.

Hope this will be helpful for others running into the same situation.

Regards,

Cristina